# How to make a 2d cloud texture more "stylized"?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, node-editor

I've figured out how to render out cloud textures to a sphere for an easy way to make hdris for ue skies.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SV4Vy.jpg) Is what I have done now. It looks alright but it's far to realistic for my needs. The video tuts I've seen always end with a cloud mesh or some sort of volumetric effect. I *specifically* do not want this to be 3d, I need a simple 2d cloud texture.

Any blender masters here are able to tell me some tricks or tips on how to make this more stylized? I'm a noob so I'm not aware of very many texture nodes or things I could potentially do to make the texture better.

End result would hopefully be something similar to ghibli or the witness or some indies title. Any help appreciated, thanc.

With Christopher Bennett's settings I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfVRT.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you're going for, but you could try something like this.

[image: Clouds]

The general idea is that I made the cloud "clusters" by using a Noise texture to slightly warp the input vector of a Voronai Texture. Doing this, and choosing the distance output of the Voronai texture can create "warped circles", which can be more tightly defined with a ColorRamp. This only makes the spaces where the clouds will go - to get the slightly fluffy look, I used a different Noise Texture to "fill in the gaps". This gives more (and separate) control of the cloud look, without affecting the edge detail.

To achieve the final look, I tinted the dark values from the Noise Ttexture to be the same color as the sky, and then added the values to the sky color, using the Voronai "warped circles" as a mix factor. You can control the detail of the clouds using both the Scale and Detail values of the Noise Texture, as well as through manipulation of the ColorRamp(s).

You can then render the image and take it into the compositor and apply a filter. "Sharpen" or Shadow" seem to be a good place to start.

[image: Sharpen]

[image: Shadow]

Comment: That actually looks pretty damn nice, thanks! I actually don't need the sky at all, just clouds unreal engine can handle the rest, but again thanks. I'll update you in a bit after some testing, cheers!

Comment: Man there are so many layers to this program I feel like everytime I open it I learn more things

Comment: I agree - It really is quite the program. Almost unbelievable it's free, especially given what Autodesk and the like charge for similar stuff.

Comment: I updated my post, not getting the same results as you. Maybe because my mesh the texture is getting applied to is a gigantic skysphere?

Comment: If you want it for a sky, you should begin with the same input vectors you used to achieve the sky effect in your first example. I will try to build the graph for a sky texture, but it might be a little while. I'll post it here when I have it.

Comment: Alright lemme give it a go! Thanks for your time man!